# using flask and getting error : TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Tags: python, python-2.7

have been searching the web for answer but didnt find solution :(

 i am running simple code and getting :

#### TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

here as the code, appreciate the assist

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from flask import Flask
import subprocess
import os

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def main():
    return "Welcome!"
    

@app.route("/unix/")
def run_command_on_unix():

        a = os.system("date")
        return a



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

Comment: on which line are you getting this error ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want to return the output of command `date` as a response. The `os.system('date')` returns zero which is of type `int`. Hence the error. You could use `os.popen` to read the output of the command.

```
@app.route("/unix/")
def run_command_on_unix():
        a = os.popen("date").read()
        return a
```

Comment: To be more exact: `os.system(somecmd)` returns the exit code of the "somecmd" process, which can be `0` (=> success) or just any integer (=>error).